# Conditional Merging Pandas

Tags: pandas

I wish to perform conditional merging, below is my dataframe named df. I wish to merge reference df_reference with df over weight.
Merging should be such that weight should be equal or less.
Example: row 1 weight is 62.2, this need to be merged with weight 60.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
name    weight
Arash   62.2
Bash    98.2
Kim     88.2
Dim     92.1
Ghst    63.2
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Reference table

```
reference = """
weight  performance
60   100
65    95
70    93
75    92
80    90
85    85
90    79
95    75
"""

df_reference = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(reference), delim_whitespace=True)
```

**Below is expected output:**

```
output = """
name    weight   weight_l    performance_l
Arash   62.2       60           100       
Bash    91.2       90           79       
Kim     88.2       85           85      
Dim     92.1       90           95
Ghst    63.2       60           65      
"""

df_expectation = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(output), delim_whitespace=True)
```

I can merge when there is exact match, but not able to do when the match is not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
df_reference.columns = ['weight_l', 'performance_l']
df['weight_l'] = df['weight'] // 10 * 10
df.loc[df['weight'] % 10 > 5, 'weight_l'] = df.loc[df['weight'] % 10 > 5, 'weight_l'] + 5
df_expectation = pd.merge(df,df_reference, on=['weight_l'])
```